# How to Save "\r" and "\n" Inside of a Column

Tags: sql-server, wpf, string, nhibernate

**Goal**:
Save the data `11111\r\n11111\r\n111111\r\n\r\n22222\r\n22222\r\n22222\r\n22222\r\n\r\n` inside of a column. This column is `varchar(1000)`.

**Problem**:
The data of `\r` and `\n` will not be saved inside of the column. I have reflected and where should I start?

**Information**:
I have retrieved the data from a variable string in WPF and then I want to paste it inside of a column.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is being saved, you just cannot see it in the results view.  `\r\n` is a C# string escape sequence that represents a newline on Windows.  It looks like the results table is representing newlines with a space so that the row doesn't grow vertically.

If you fetch the data from code, the newline characters will still be there.

Comment: Maybe change the output to text. That way you will see it.

Comment: CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) ?